# whenever try to push onto stack gives error in java null pointer exception

Tags: java

In this code as user enters string it is pushed onto stack and if "-" appears then previous string is popped out and when the stack becomes empty then loop execution stops.
Whenever I try to push onto stack null pointer exception is there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class StackArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        StackArrayModel stack = new StackArrayModel();
        while (true) {
            String data = scan.next();
            if (data.equals("-")) {
                if (stack.isEmpty() == false)
                    System.out.println(stack.pop());
                else
                    break;
            } else {
                stack.push(data);
            }
        }
    }
}

// creating resizable array stack
class StackArrayModel {
    String[] s;
    int n = 0;

    public void StackArrayModel() {
        s = new String[1];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return n == 0;
    }

    public void push(String item) {
        if (n == s.length) {
            resize(s.length * 2);
        }
        s[n++] = item;
    }

    private void resize(int capacity) {
        String[] copy = new String[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            copy[i] = s[i];
        }
        s = copy;
    }

    public String pop() {
        if (n > 0 && n == s.length / 4)
            resize(s.length / 2);
        String item = s[--n];
        s[n] = null;
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide required `stacktrace` of the log. Looks like you want to write a `constructor` and ended up with `method` name `public void StackArrayModel()`. `Constructor` has not any return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in `StackArrayModel` class. You didn't overwrite the default constructor, because you added a `void` there.

```
public void StackArrayModel(){
    s = new String[1] ;
}
```

should be changed to following so it overwrites the default constructor:

```
public StackArrayModel(){
    s = new String[1] ;
}
```

Once you did that, you've overwritten the default constructor, and your code should work just fine.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It is indeed not necessarily an error, but the naming (capital letter) suggests that this was the intention.